# Abort statement

Tags: ada, gnat

I'm trying to abort a task in ada program but I get this error during compilation:

```
expect task name or task interface class-wide object for "abort"
```

The code looks like this:

```
task type Sending_Message;
type Send_Message is access Sending_Message;

declare
    send    : Send_Message;
begin
    send := new Sending_Message;
    ...
    abort send;   -- this line throws error
end;
```

And again when I try line like this:

```
abort Sending_Message;
```

I get error:

```
invalid use of subtype mark in expression or call
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to explicitly dereference the access type:

```
abort send.all;
```